# How to find non English character in Oracle SQL developer

Tags: sql, oracle, informatica

Query to find non English character or multibyte character for NCLOB datatype field
Example : Japanese, Chinese characters.

Answer (score 2):

You may use `regexp_replace` and regex class exclusion operator (`^`) to extract the range you need or without exclusion to extract symbols not in the class.

Below are some examples to extract letters of specific languages as well as everything non-latin.

> ```
> with a(input) as (
>   select *
>   from sys.odcivarchar2list(
>     'ぁqwかджさたな嗢还没はas花了фやdйцhjке'
>   )
> )
> select
>   input,
>   /*                                                                       */
>   regexp_replace(input, unistr('[^\0400-\04FF]+')) as Cyrillic,
>   regexp_replace(input, unistr('[^\0041-\007A]+')) as Latin,
>   regexp_replace(input, unistr('[^\3041-\3096]+')) as Hiragana,
>   regexp_replace(input, unistr('[^\4E00-\9FFF]+')) as CJK,
>   regexp_replace(input, unistr('[\0041-\007A]+')) as non_Latin
>
> from a
> ```
>
> | INPUT | CYRILLIC | LATIN | HIRAGANA | CJK | NON_LATIN |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | ぁqwかджさたな嗢还没はas花了фやdйцhjке | джфйцке | qwasdhj | ぁかさたなはや | 嗢还没花了 | ぁかджさたな嗢还没は花了фやйцке |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=bf12959bbb601e75504407a202478182)*